# can't set "Long Lived Facebook Access Tokens" from about 2 months to never expire?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I make some service to auto post to a page with Registered.

but I don't want my users to log in every two months. To only just generate a new Long Lived Facebook Access Tokens.

how or way to auto renew Long Lived Facebook Access Tokens?

Comment: Long-lived page access tokens do not have a default expiry.

Comment: @CBroe Oh. Thank you. but what is Data Access Expires?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/auth-vs-data